# Typeclass like `IsList` without the `fromList` function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

The `GHC.Exts` module exports the [`IsList`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/OverloadedLists) typeclass:

```
class IsList l where
  type Item l
  fromList  :: [Item l] -> l
  toList    :: l -> [Item l]

  fromListN :: Int -> [Item l] -> l
  fromListN _ = fromList
```

I have a data-type defined as follows:

```
newtype MyData = MyData { toMap :: Map (RefTo X) X }
```

Somtimes it is convenient to work with the elements of `MyData` in a list, and since there's a bijection between `Ref X` and `X`, I thought about defining a `IsList` instance for `MyData`.

Now the problem is that the constructor `MyData` is not exposed, and values of type `MyData` can only be created via a (smart?) constructor of the form:

```
mkMyData :: [X] -> Either Error MyData
```

So defining a `fromList` will defeat the purpose of the smart constructor.

Is there a type-class like `IsList` such that instances of this class can be converted to a list, but not the other way?

Comment: The question title seems to conflict with the body.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I've corrected the title.

Comment: Perhaps [`MonoFoldable` from `mono-traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.8.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable)?

Comment: It seems like `otoList :: mono -> [Element mono]` will do, but I'd have to define a bunch of other functions that I don't need :/

Comment: If you're comfortable with the idea of lenses, you've described exactly what a `Prism` is.

Comment: Why do you need a typeclass? What is your goal? Can't you define your own typeclass with only the methods you need?

Comment: I'll look into `Prism`s then. @chi I have a lot of these kinds of `MyData` structures (nested into each other), so instead of having several functions `MyDataNToList` I'd like to use the type-class function.

Comment: How about `Foldable`?  It has `toList`, and once you can convert to a list you can fold.

Comment: I thought about that, bot `MyData` has kind `*`.